# How can I download an image with ajax and then replace it as div backgrounds?

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax, image

So the concept here I have, is that I download a .jpg or .png that has all the interface images on it (arrows, buttons, borders etc used throughout the site). Then when I want to use one, I just make a div:

```
<div id="img_left_arrow"></div>
```

Then in the css, I reference the part of the image that I want:

```
.img_left_arrow {
    background-image:url("path/to/file.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:-24px -80px;
    width:200px;
    height:400px;
}
```

So this image would be located at 24px across, 80px down on file.png, and the image would be 200x400px. So now where the div is, the image will show.

The first thing I would like to do is to show a progress bar (I will be using one for everything on the site) that will show the progress of the image loading. This will load the image into a hidden div. So at the moment to get other items (like all js used in the site etc), I would do something like this (we will just use getting a script for the example):

-the empty progress bar

```
<div id="mainLoadProg"></div>
```

-the hidden div for the code (this will have css to hide it)

```
<div id="jscriptCode"></div>
```

-the php to get the size of the code (size.php)

```
echo strlen(json_encode(file_get_contents("path/to/file.js")));
```

-the actual code (code.php)

```
echo json_encode(file_get_contents("path/to/file.js"));
```

-the jquery code to run (client side)

```
$(function() {
    $('#mainLoadProg').progressbar({ value: 0 });
    //get the size first
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "size.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(recData) {
            loadPageContent(recData); //run function with data size
        }
    });
});

//function to receive data and show progress bar
function loadPageContent(size) {
    $.ajax({
        xhr: function() {
            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
                downloadedAmount = evt.loaded;
                downloadedPercent = (downloadedAmount / size)*100;
                $('#mainLoadProg').progressbar({ value: downloadedPercent });
            }, false);
            return xhr;
        },
        type: "POST",
        url: "code.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(recData) {
            $("#jscriptCode").html(recData); //load the code from the php page into the div
        }
    });
});
```

Of course it is no use loading a php page that just has:

```
<img src="path/to/file.png">
```

as it will just load the code, and not the image content. I was thinking something in the PHP like:

```
echo json_encode(base64_encode(file_get_contents("path/to/file.png")));
```

and that way I could use strlen to get the file size to be downloaded as well. But once I throw the base64 string into the div, what is the most resource efficient way to then make it the background image in the div? Of course I can not use "path/to/file.png" as it would just re-download the image!

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm with you on the "use a single image as the background for multiple elements" - that's quite common, and is called [css sprites](https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/). The part where you lose me is when you start talking about getting the image from PHP, or loading the image in a hidden div. Just link to it in your CSS, and it will load once.

Comment: The code above will do the css sprites part, however, I can not load the image using a progress bar. I need to use an ajax call to use the progress bar. This means on a mobile phone or slow connection, the user can see how much of the site is loaded. I will add an example into the question.

Comment: _"The first thing I would like to do is to show a progress bar (I will be using one for everything on the site) that will show the progress of the image loading."_ Not certain interpret Question correctly ? Where is image loading ?

Comment: The image will load into a hidden div. Once it is down, it will then need to be added into the styles. See the updated example. This code is how I load all the js (and there will be a LOT of js, probably over 1mb of minimized code) and am able to give feedback etc. I want to do this with the css sprite images as well. In my real code, I will return an array with all sizes, and then loop through loading the different kinds of content (using the total size, not the size of that file) to update the progress bar. This means the user will just see a progress bar load and then the page appear.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly this might help!
https://gist.github.com/markmichon/6510134

Comment: I'm not sure how that is supposed to help. All that code seems to do is make a div with the text loading and a loading gif while the ajax call is being made. There is nothing to do with transferring images via ajax etc. My code is already working WAY better than that, as it makes an actual progress bar, not just an animated gif.